# SQL Connection fails (timeout) but works in classic VB6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, vb6

I am converting a VB6 app to .NET

The VB6 app connects to a MS SQL Server fine and always has via an ADODB Connection. I set it up using a connection string.

The SQL Server is on the network, it is not on the local machine.

When I try to connect using the same connection string in .NET (VB or C#) I get a "timeout expired" error. I return to my VB6 app and it connects up just fine.

I am not able to amend the network set up as it is not my network.
The C# code I am using is below:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CommandLineApp
{
  public class ConnectionDemo
  {
    public static void Main(string [] args)
    {
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection
      (
        @"Data Source=192.168.0.5;" + 
        "Initial Catalog=mydb;" +
        "User Id=myid;" +
        "Password=mypass;"
      );
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
     }
  }
}
```

I have tried all sorts of different things in the connection string including using the server name, using "tcp:,port".

Interestingly enough I am not able to ping the server on IPv6 ("ping -6 ")

I remind you that I am unable to make changes to the network as it is not mine however the VB6 code works just fine. Same connection string. So I don't see why I should have to alter the network.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a firewall or access filter that is allowing the vb6 exe through but blocking your .net app? Did you have a look through these options? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852320/vb6-applications-can-connect-to-sql-server-but-net-applications-cant

Comment: Let us see the connection string used by the VB6 app, also is this VB6 app running on a machine for which ports were perhaps opened in firewalls ? You often need ports opened for application to be able to reach SQL clusters in corporate environments.

Comment: @Mort I will get the Network guys to look at that.

Comment: @Francis The VB6 connection string looks like this: "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=myid;password=mypass;Initial Catalog=mydb;Data Source=192.168.0.5" pretty much the same except for the provider

Comment: Inserting "np:<servername>" to force Named Pipes has fixed this issue. Don't know if that is a workaround but it has worked using SqlConnection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB; " +
"Data Source=192.168.0.5; " + 
"Initial Catalog=mydb; " +
"User Id=myid; " +
"Password=mypass; ");
```

Comment: I think the solution will be somewhere along these lines as I guess the issue is IPv6, however the "PrefferedAddressFamily" is not a recognized command in MSSQL I think it is just Oracle DBs

Comment: Using the OleDbConnection instead of the SqlConnection object and providing the Provider has fixed the issue. Thanks.